# lazy variable with closure

Tags: swift, lazy-evaluation

In this [article](https://medium.com/swift-programming/how-to-do-proper-lazy-loading-in-swift-b8bc57dbc7b9), it says (referencing the code below): "You must use lazy to prevent the closure for being created more than once."

```
private lazy var variable:SomeClass = {
    let fVariable = SomeClass()
    fVariable.value = 10
    return fVariable
}()
```

Why would lazy prevent the closure from being created more than once? And why would the lack of lazy cause it to evaluate more than once?

Comment: The explanation in my book is better: http://www.apeth.com/swiftBook/ch03.html#_lazy_initialization

Comment: Thanks - book explanation is excellent.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The tutorial code you quote is this:

```
private lazy var variable:SomeClass = {
    let fVariable = SomeClass()
    fVariable.value = 10
    return fVariable
}()
```

Contrast it with this:

```
private var variable:SomeClass {
    let fVariable = SomeClass()
    fVariable.value = 10
    return fVariable
}
```

The first one initializes `variable` to a newly created SomeClass instance, *once at most* (and maybe not even that many times). The second one is a read-only computed variable and creates a new SomeClass instance every time its value is read.

Comment: I was looking at [this post](https://medium.com/p/b8bc57dbc7b9/responses/show) and the label that's lazily instantiated has a call to add it to the view before returning it. Is that correct, or should you just return the label?

Answer (score 13):

Your intuition is right, that article is incorrect. I'm guessing the author is conflating/confusing computed property syntax with the immediately-executed-closure trick. The `lazy` keyword has nothing to do with how many times the closure is executed. `lazy` simply causes the property to remain uninitialized until first access, at which point the expression on the right hand side of the equal sign is evaluated.

To simplify, this:

```
var myVar: MyType {
    return MyType()
}
```

is very different than this:

```
var myVar: MyType = MyType()
```

which is similar in storage but has different initialization semantics than this:

```
lazy var myVar: MyType = MyType()
```

In the first example, `myVar` is a computed property and the code inside of the curly braces is executed every time `myVar` is accessed. In other words, every time you access `myVar` you'd get a newly created object back.

In the second example, `myVar` is a stored property and the expression after the equal sign is evaluated once during initialization of the class or struct that contains that property.

In the third example, `myVar` is still a stored property but the evaluation of the expression after the equal sign (be it an initializer expression, a function invocation, or a closure invocation) is delayed until it's accessed.

As a side note, this line of code:

```
lazy var myVar: MyType = { ... }()
```

is equivalent to:

```
func doStuffAndReturnMyType() { ... }
lazy var myVar: MyType = doStuffAndReturnMyType()
```

The shorthand in the first example wasn't specifically designed for–it just works because Swift's type system (is awesome and) treats closures as unnamed (anonymous) functions.

Comment: Am I right that trailing brackets not needed in this line `func doStuffAndReturnMyType() { ... }()`?

Comment: @ShadowOf Good catch, my mistake. I've edited the post to fix it.

Comment: Could you clarify the immediately-executed-closure trick?

It seems to me that the suffixed "()" means that the property will return the return value as opposed to the closure, and i dont quite understand how the trick fits into all of this