# Alamofire - error code -999

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

I wrote

```
class Property{
    ...
    static var alamofireManager: SessionManager{
        let sessionConfiguration = URLSessionConfiguration.default
        sessionConfiguration.timeoutIntervalForRequest = 10
        return Alamofire.SessionManager(configuration: sessionConfiguration)
    }
    ...
}
```

for multiple classes' functions to use it.

However, when I use it:

```
Property.alamofireManager.request(loginURL).validate(contentType: ["application/json"]).responseJSON{ response in
....
```

I get error saying :

> Task <1F6C95AA-C878-439F-87ED-1055D19E3ADD>.<1> finished with error - code: -999

I know it works if I just use Alamofire. Does anyone know why this is not working?

Thank you!

Comment: My guess is because you're not creating any headers unlike Alamofire's default SessionManager. Therefore important information is missing such as `Accept-Encoding` and `Accept-Language`.

Comment: You're also missing parentheses `()` after the var closure. Explanation here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33115013/1433612

Comment: Hmm I see. Let me try later and update. Thank you by the way!

Comment: try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/52868844/5032981

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's what it should look like:

```
static let alamofireManager: SessionManager = {
    let sessionConfiguration = URLSessionConfiguration.default
    sessionConfiguration.timeoutIntervalForRequest = 10
    return Alamofire.SessionManager(configuration: sessionConfiguration)
}()
```